# Best Fit a document in Richtextbox

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

Using C# How can I show a document in richtextbox without scrollbars, But I need like a bestfit mode? I mean what we are seeing like a preview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the **Multiline** property to **true**, the contents should word wrap. That will take care of your horizontal scroll bars.